# HIVE_CANNOT_OPEN_SPLIT : Column <column_name> type null not supported

Tags: apache-spark, parquet, presto, amazon-athena

HIVE_CANNOT_OPEN_SPLIT: Error opening Hive split s3://path/to/file/<>.snappy.parquet : Column ai.ja type null not supported

This only happens when I define an "JA" column, which is a struct of string. If I leave the column out, I can query without issues. The schema information was gotten from our parquet file using Apache Spark.

```
 The create table statement I'm using to reproduce the error follows:
  CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE <<tablename>>(`ai` struct < acs : varchar(100), ltc : varchar(100), primaryapplicant : struct < bwh : varchar(10), citizenship : varchar(20), currentaddresscity : varchar(50), currentaddressstate : varchar(50), currentaddressstreet2 : varchar(50), ss : varchar(50)>, JA : array < struct < dateofbirth : varchar(50), emailaddress : varchar(50), firstname : varchar(50), lastname : varchar(50), ss : varchar(50)>>, status : varchar(50), uri : varchar(50)>, `pr` struct < pc : struct < cn : varchar(50)>>, `product` array < struct < at : varchar(20), pi : varchar(50), pmn : varchar(256)>>, `ipt` varchar(40) ) PARTITIONED BY ( `owner` varchar(40) ) ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat' OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat' LOCATION 's3://<location>' TBLPROPERTIES ( 'compression_type' = 'snappy', 'numRows' = '2', 'transient_lastDdlTime' = <> )
```

Which is reading from a parquet file.

```
 Parquet schema : 
  root
 |-- ai: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- acs: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- JA: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- DateOfBirth: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- EmailAddress: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- FirstName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- LastName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- ss: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- ltc: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- PrimaryApplicant: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- bwh: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Citizenship: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- CurrentAddressCity: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- CurrentAddressState: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- CurrentAddressStreet2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- ss: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Status: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |-- pr: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- pc: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cn: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Product: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- at: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- pi: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- pmn: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ipt: string (nullable = true)
```

The same issue was put up on this link https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=246551.
 But still not able to figure it out.

Can anyone help?

Comment: There is nothing obvious here. Can you try starting with a working schema, and then add one single "small" field until it fails?  I would also try making the field names lowercase, and dropping the numeric constraint on the `VARCHAR` types (e.g. `VARCHAR` instead of `VARCHAR(50)`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue is resolved.

For creating an Athena table every field should map exactly to the schema i.e., the order of each field should be the same as that of the schema.